# Generalization arg max for a value for a function of the g(max(f)) or preimage of g?

Tags: notation, terminology

I want to refer to the argument value $x_o$ in which the function takes a given value, $f(x) = 0.5\ \text{max}_x(f(x))$.

Note that this value is a function of the max, $g(y) = 0.5\ y$

Can I use a generalization of arg max, arg min etc as?

$x_o = \text{arg}\ 0.5\ \text{max}_x (f(x))$

Or do I need to use the preimage as

$x_o = f^{-1}[g(\text{max}_x (f(x)))] = f^{-1}[0.5\ \text{max}_x (f(x))]$

Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: $$x_o \in f^{-1}\left(\frac {\max_x f(x)}2\right)$$ would be best. You can only replace the "$\in$" with "$=$" if you know that $f$ is one-to-one.

Comment: Good point about the "$\in$" and "$=$". But in relation to that, is $f^{-1}(\cdot)$ correct? I thought I had to use $f^{-1}[\cdot]$ because as you said $f(\cdot)$ doesn't need to be invertible, so I don't want $f^{-1}$ to mean *inverse of f* but preimage.

Comment: @PaulSinclair or both notations are fine?

Comment: Personally, I've never seen anyone make a distinction between $f^{-1}(\cdot)$ and $f^{-1}[\cdot]$. The only time I ever see someone using square brackets for this is because there are other parentheses around, and using brackets instead helps keep straight which groupings end where.